# How to isolate or debug issues specific to IE 10 and 11?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I put together a web app that looks great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but when it comes to IE 10 and 11, it just falls apart. As a matter of fact, it works worse in IE 11 than 10.

In IE 11, a `<canvas>` element won't even show up, and some `<div>` elements look really strange and don't have a border-radius, even though I specified it in the CSS. Unfortunately, there are no errors in the console and frankly I'm not seeing where the problems are coming in to play within the CSS and JS.

***What would one do in such a situation where you don't really see any good starting point to debug IE?***

I was hoping that running things through W3C Validator and JSHint / lint would help, but even those are entirely clean.  It would be nice to find some tool to make this a cleaner process as well aside from these noted, but so far I'm shooting blanks.

Comment: With regards to the IE11 border radius bug, it might be because it is using compatibility view to render the page, if the page is hosted locally. [Try this solution](http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/03/fix-css-border-radius-not-working-in.html).

Comment: Compatibility mode will break `<canvas>` as well...

Comment: @Terry Holy crap, it appears that that just made the whole page render correctly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [some reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_mode#Internet_Explorer) Microsoft decided to enable "Compatibility mode" in IE 8 and on (now renamed to "Emulation" in IE 11).  The purpose of this is to be able to see websites in a legacy mode so that one can develop sites and see how it will look on older browsers and even make it work "correctly" on sites that are not using current web standards for their design, etc.

Unfortunately they have made it default to ON for local area network connections.  Seems like a skewed choice, but as Terry noted in the comment, it is indeed a problem with a solution:

**From [this](http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/03/fix-css-border-radius-not-working-in.html) blog post**:

> The solution [is] to disable IE11’s Compatibility View for intranet
>   sites by doing Setting (gear icon) > Compatibility View Settings >
>   uncheck “Display intranet sites in Compatibility View” checkbox. 
>   Making that configuration change immediately [gets] IE11 to start
>   rendering the page properly.